# Excel file comparing with python and regex

Tags: python, regex, excel

Got two excel files, one with a little ammount of id's and other with tonns of id's + ip address:

How do i compare them line by line, and then print out a concatenation of id(first file) and id+ip(second file) cells that matched with id's?

Where could i go further from here?

```
import re

router_id = r'[0-9]{5}'  # regex for finding 5-num-symboled id like '65432'
ip_multi = r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}'  # for finding ip address


def parsing_func(filename, method):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    lines = str(file.readlines())
    exp_data = re.findall(method, lines)
    return exp_data

table_id = set(parsing_func('file1.txt', router_id))
table_addr = set(parsing_func('file2.txt', router_id))
table_mk = set(parsing_func('file2.txt', ip_multi))

content = '\n'.join(table_id)

print(content)
```

Comment: You haven't shown us your data, but it would probably be much quicker to do it in Excel using `VLOOKUP()`.

Comment: it is like "65432 | 65432 = 172.20.20.20"

Comment: Is that what your source data looks like, or how you want the result to look?

Comment: these are from two separated files. i want to check if 65432 from the first file is present in the other one. If True: print it with address like this  65432 = 172.20.20.20.

Comment: Excel recipe: Edit your big file to put the IDs and IP addresses in separate columns (Data | Text to columns). Edit your small file and add the formula =VLOOKUP(A1,'[mybigfile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$32767,2,0) in cell B1 and copy to all rows below it. You're done.

Comment: Hah, many thanks, but the goal was to make it exactly with python :)